# How can I make Sphinx's inheritance_diagram readable?

Tags: python, graphviz, python-sphinx

Similar to [this chap's post](http://groups.google.com/group/sphinx-dev/browse_thread/thread/6bdbc72cb82dab9/e81592216cd30fc4?lnk=gst&q=attributes#e81592216cd30fc4), I'm seeing Sphinx generate unreadable graphviz output:

[image]

How can I generate readable output?

- Nothing happens if I add `-Gfontsize=140`
- If I tell it to use `neato` instead of `dot` it produces readable output, but the graphs aren't tree-like.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured out the answer from [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/sphinx-dev/browse_thread/thread/bc0f04997d8a3ac6/e7335502302927e6?show_docid=e7335502302927e6).  In the `graphviz.py` code, they have a default value for the size of the graph at 8.0x12.0.  If you want to allow Graphviz to determine the size you need to put this in `conf.py` so the [Sphinx graphviz extension](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/ext/graphviz.html) uses your empty string instead of its default:

```
inheritance_graph_attrs = dict(size='""')
```

Also, if you're hitting this issue then the graph may be too wide once you allow the size to be determined by Graphviz.  You'll additionally want attribute `rankdir="TB"` so the tree goes from top to bottom instead of left to right:

```
inheritance_graph_attrs = dict(rankdir="TB", size='""')
```